# Vertically offset underscore \_ in paragraph

Tags: fonts, macros, typography

I'm trying to vertically offset some underscores in a filename representation: `some_file_name.ext` so that the underscore is moved above the baseline. Here is what I tried def'ing:

```tex
\def\raiseunderscore#1-#2{\dimexpr\height#1#2\relax}
```

but I'm getting error: *! You can't use `\dimexpr' in restricted horizontal mode.*

So in my notoriously fragmented competence on TeX primitives, I tried:

```tex
\def\raiseunderscore#1-#2{\leavevmode\dimexpr\height#1#2\relax}
```

to no avail.

How can I vertically offset the underscore character when used in normal text as _? Also, is there a way I can have this occur in all instances (globally) instead of making a macro for it?

**Update:**
Here is what I am trying to achieve (I've changed the macro name for brevity) :

[image: raised by some]

[image: raised by a lot]

[image: lowered by a lot]

Here is a short MVE of what I've tried so far:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\def\offsetchr#1#2{\dimexpr\height#1#2\relax}
\begin{document}

This sentence has a raised\quad\offsetchr{15pt}{\_} \quad character in the middle.

This sentence also has a raised\quad\offsetchr{2.5em}{\_} \quad character in the middle.

This sentence has a lowered\quad\offsetchr{-2.5em}{\_} \quad character in the middle.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\dimexpr` just computes an (dimension) expression, it doesn't move things around.  Can you please show a compilable example of what you're trying?

Comment: Added what you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example with `\dimexpr` is not understandable for me, so for TeX too. Of course, you cannot use `\dimexpr` in the typesetting material without any context.

But you can use `\raise\hbox` primitive construction and set the `_` as an active character when the parameter of the `\filename` is read:

```
{\catcode`_13 
   \gdef_{\raise.35ex\hbox{\string_}}
}
\def\filename{\bgroup\catcode`_=13 \filenameA}
\def\filenameA#1{\tt#1\egroup}

% test:
\filename{some_file_name.ext}
```

Comment: Just to relieve the intense suspense as to why I posted a question with `\dimexpr` is simply because I found this as an answer somewhere online, but as it didn't work (and my questionable understanding of primitives) I posted it here since it is what i've tried and searched for. `\raise0.2ex\hbox{\_}` did it for me in the particular place i needed it, but no answer has provided a global solution (for all paragraph text).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need backslashes in the file names, you can do with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\filename}{m}
 {
  \aldric_filename:n { #1 }
 }

\str_new:N \l_aldric_filename_str
\tl_new:N \l_aldric_filename_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { NV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aldric_filename:n
 {
  % stringify the file name
  \str_set:Nn \l_aldric_filename_str { #1 }
  % define a token list with it
  \tl_set:Nx \l_aldric_filename_tl { \str_use:N \l_aldric_filename_str }
  % replace all _ with a macro for a raised underscore
  \tl_replace_all:NVn \l_aldric_filename_tl \c_underscore_str { \aldric_filename_raised_us: }
  % deliver the result
  \texttt{ \tl_use:N \l_aldric_filename_tl }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aldric_filename_raised_us:
 {
  \raisebox { 0.2ex } { \c_underscore_str } % fix the parameter to suit
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\filename{some_file_name.ext}

\filename{some_$tr@ng&_file_name.txt}

{\footnotesize\filename{some_file_name.ext}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, flawlessly. But I don't have the slightest clue how. I'm not in any way versed in ExplSyntax. I assume that you somehow capture the underscore with `\c_underscore_str` and raise it with a `\raisebox`?

Comment: @OleAldric Yes, `\c_underscore_str` is a constant string containing the standard “printable” underscore. The indirection is needed because `_` has a special use under `\ExplSyntaxOn`.